# Given a char* with the prototype, can we cast a void* to a function pointer? and run it?

Tags: c

I've declared many functions in one driver, and am **passing the pointers to the functions to another driver** in a list with the node format:

```
struct node
{
 char def_prototype[256]; //example:(int (*)(wchar, int, int))
 void *def_function;
};
```

Is there a way to typecast **def_function** to the prototype given in **def_prototype**?

Currently I'm using simple switch and strcmp, but I wanted to generalize it if possible.
PS: I know that casting between void pointer and function pointer is unsafe (as mentioned in various places in SO), but desperate times call for desperate measures and I have taken lot of care.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the lack in clarity. I want to actually call the function (not just cast it), making a function pointer at runtime based on the char[] provided.

**EDIT AGAIN:**
Since I'm working at the kernel level (**windows driver**), I don't have access to much resources, so, I'm sticking to my current implementation (with some changes to kill back-doors). Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: Are you aware that unintended overflow in def_prototype array will override pointer to function ? This will allow Dr. Evil to blow up your code and take control of the world :-)

Comment: @Bart, shhh... every programmer leave himself a backdoor :P

Comment: OO thanks Bart, I'll figure out a solution for that quickly..

Comment: @Bart: the problem is not so much dangerous to the world with an unintended overflow as with an **intended** overflow

Comment: Where would you get the parameters for the function call from? E.g. your example function takes a wchar and two ints; what would you call it with?

Comment: @ammoQ: from the other driver, where we have all the data, just methods need to be invoked.

Comment: But somewhere you need some logic that maps your possible input data to the parameters those functions actually need. A varchar and two ints -> use a, x, y. Two varchars -> use a,b. Three ints -> use x, y, z. etc.

Comment: Coming to think of it, the question doesn't make sense. There will be no absolute generalization, at some place or the other, comparing and assertion will be there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good implementation of similar ideas is [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/). This implements the gory details of declaring and calling functions with arbitrary calling conventions and signatures. It is (surprisingly) platform portable, and known to work on Linux and Windows out of the box.

An example of its use is the Lua extension library [alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/). That demonstrates calling arbitrary functions declared at runtime and adapting from native Lua types to the types required for the calling conventions. The specific Lua binding won't be useful to you, but it serves as a complete working example of how and why one might actually use libffi.

Answer (score 5):

ISO-C does not allow casting between function and data pointers, ie you should use a `void (*)(void)` instead of a `void *` to hold your function.

That aside, YeenFei is correct in his assertion that there is no general platform-independant solution, meaning the best you can do in C itself is to supply a list of supported signatures.

You should implement your own encoding scheme instead of using plain C prototypes. It's common to use a string where each char represents a function argument (and the first one the return value); a function of type `int (*)(wchar, int, int)` for example could have the signature `"iwii"`.

Signature lookup tables can then be easily built using `bsearch()` and `strcmp()`; here's a complete example:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int cmp(const void *key, const void *element)
{
    return strcmp(key, *(const char * const *)element);
}

static _Bool dispatch(const char *sig, void (*func)(void), void *retval, ...)
{
    // supported signatures; must be ordered according to strcmp()
    static const char * const SIGS[] = { "iii", "v", "vi" };

    const char * const *match = bsearch(
        sig, SIGS, sizeof SIGS / sizeof *SIGS, sizeof *SIGS, cmp);

    if(!match) return 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, retval);

    switch(match - SIGS)
    {
        case 0: {   // iii
            int a1 = va_arg(args, int);
            int a2 = va_arg(args, int);
            int rv = ((int (*)(int, int))func)(a1, a2);
            if(retval) memcpy(retval, &rv, sizeof rv);
            break;
        }

        case 1: {   // v
            func();
            break;
        }

        case 2: {   // vi
            int a1 = va_arg(args, int);
            ((void (*)(int))func)(a1);
            break;
        }

        default:
        assert(!"PANIC");
    }

    va_end(args);
    return 1;
}

// example code:

static int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum;
    dispatch("iii", (void (*)(void))add, &sum, 3, 4);
    printf("%i", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks, your answer was the most useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

unless you want to mess with assembly thunking (pushing data onto stack before jumping, etc), there is better way other than doing some switch case.

if the destination function is finite and known, why not create a lookup table (`map<string, functor>`) for it ?

Comment: much better than my solution, but I'm working at driver level, where I don't think map is available. by the way it's c, not c++

Answer (score 0):

Since C has no runtime type information, there is absolutely no need to do a dynamic cast as you are considering. Just pass the pointer and if everything fits, it will work. If the pointer doesn't point to a function with the right signature, there is no way to fix it.

Comment: i think the author is asking for a method to runtime generate function prototype based on the string contents, then call given function(address) with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two solutions:

1. Go to the assembly level and parse the prototype string there and put the arguments you find in the prototype there where the other function will expect them.
2. Make a long list of all supported prototypes and compare the current one with the list. When you find a match, you can make the typecast as needed. The most common structure for this test would ba an `if`-`else` ladder.